# Display PDF in iframe in Mobile Chrome instead of downloading to device

Tags: html, pdf, mobile, iframe

I have a page with an iframe that displays a PDF file. It works fine in every browser except mobile Chrome. When the page opens, the PDF downloads to the phone or tablet and the page appears empty. Is there a way to force the file to display rather than downloading?

Answer (score 4):

This question are very old, but I find it in top of google ))
For everyone who is looking for the solution: try to use http://googlesystem.blogspot.ru/2009/09/embeddable-google-document-viewer.html

If your file avalible via internet (and do not require autorisation on site), you can embed it with iframe.

Comment: This doesn't seem to answer the question - the OP is already using an iframe.

Comment: This is a different approach - and it will work on mobile as OP wants